# What is the proper setup/architecture of postfix, phpmail, and and open mail relay service?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmailer, postfix-mta, emailrelay

Setup:
Ubuntu 16.x, Postfix, PHPMailer
SocketLabs (mail relay service) - to send out server emails
Union Solution Exchange Server - to send and receive formal email from outlook

Im trying to send out emails from my ubuntu linux server that contain simple form data (name, message, phone etc).
I have been trying in vain to send emails from my PHP to emails, they send, but they get blocked as spam/junk.

I've recently switched mail services (from zoho to a solution union exchange server) and I cannot get past barracuda (even modifying whitelists / spam settings etc) with my own mail, but I can see them as junk in my hotmail. (cannot not send from mailserver@potlickers.com to support@potlickers.com). They get immediately canned and not delivered.

Solutions Union said I was spoofing the emails and I cannot whitelist my own domain I'm using and sending from? Ok. They suggested buying another domain. I now own potlickers.net.

They also mentioned I should take that domain and use it to send my emails via  open relay (again socketlabs).

So, if my webserver is setup on a fqdm such as potlickers.com, and i send the mail from that server, how do i setup the correct architecture to send mails from potlickers.net to the open relayserver so my emails are free and clear and not spoofed?

Can i configure postfix to send mail from potlickers.net even though its hosting on blah.potlickers.com?

I understand to also add dkim and PTR.

Help stackoverflow1 - your my only hope. TIA much much mucho thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I got it.

Reconfigured postfix as a satellite. Pointed to smtp of relay mail server. Removed all SMTP settings in PHPmailer that point to server, and credentials.

Fire away - works like a charm.

Satellite server has the new domain potlickers.net versus the webserver domain potlickers.com

Seems to work ok for now. Will update moving forward.

Comment: Hey Scott, this is John from over at SocketLabs.com. It looks like you figured things out. But, if you end up running into any issues again, then just let me know and I'll forward your issue right over to our support team. Always happy to help!